# mix int and float in communication buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I am loading int and float values to a buffer for the purposes of transmitting the data.

some examples:

```
void send_cmd_1(int y, int z, int a, int b)
{
    int buf[5];
    buf[0] = 1;   // command #1
    buf[1] = y;   // parameters for command #1
    buf[2] = z;
    buf[3] = a;
    buf[4] = b;
    queue_command(buf);   // function to queue command
}

send_cmd_2(float x, int a)
{
    int buf[3];
    buf[0] = cmd_id;
    buf[1] = float_to_int(x);
    buf[2] = a;
    queue_command(buf);
}
```

I have many (more than 60) functions that take a command id, and some number of values that are a mixture of `int` and `float` values.  The data types of the parameters is dictated by the device that the values are being transmitted to. 
 I have no control over that.  In each of these functions, code similar to the above is executed to pack a buffer, then queue the buffer to another thread that sends the data.

I am looking for a more elegant way to do this than the brute force method of creating 60 functions that all look like slight variations of the above.

It occurs to me that a variadic template might be a good solution to this pattern.

I would like the syntax to end up something like:

```
send_cmd_1(int y, int z, int a, int b)
{
    enqueue(1, y, z, a, b);
}

send_cmd_2(float x, int a)
{
    enqueue(2, x, a);
}
```

Where '`enqueue()`' is a variadic function or template that would take a command id, and a mixture of `int` and `float` values, in the proper order, that would pack the parameters into a buffer and call the `queue_command()` function.

I need help with what enqueue looks like.

```
template<typename... Args>
void enqueue(int cmd_id, Args... args)
{
    int buf[sizeof...(Args)]
    buf[0] = cmd_id;
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof...(Args); i++)
    {
       // what goes here?
    }
    queue_command(buf);
}
```

For what it's worth, if '`Args`' is a data structure that is in the correct order, I wouldn't really need to do anything to it.  I could just queue it, as long as the bytes are in the correct order.

```
    queue_command(args);
```

Per the proposed solution, I end up with this:

```
void enqueue(cmd_enum cmd_id, Args... args)
{
    int buf[sizeof...(Args)+1U]{static_cast<int>(cmd_id), *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&args)...};
    queue_command(buf);
}
```

This gives me what I was after.

```
void send_cmd_1(int y, int z, int a, int b)
{
    enqueue(command_1_name, y, z, a, b);
}
```

Haven't tested yet.  If it doesn't work I'll post correction.

Comment: Non template overloads take precedence so you can add `void enqueue(cmd_struct const &cmd)` or `void enqueue(int cmd_id, cmd_struct const &cmd)`.

Comment: The template version won’t have the type safety of the originals (you can call `enqueue(1, 6.28, 1723)`; you should see if you can make `enqueue` into a `private` method or at least put it in a `namespace detail` (the convention for `private` when you can’t have the compiler enforce it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to understand your requirement but I suppose you can write a set of `to_int()` function, by example

```
int to_int (int i)
 { return i; }

int to_int (float f)
 { return float_to_int(f); }
```

and simply write your variadic `enqueue()` function as follows

```
template <typename ... Args>
void enqueue (int cmd_id, Args ... args)
 {
   int buf[sizeof...(Args)+1U] { cmd_id, to_int(args)... };

   queue_command(buf);
 }
```

Observe the `+1` for the dimension of `buf`: is needed for the `cmd_id`.

Comment: Do we actually need explicit conversion for each of the args?

Comment: @AndyG - I don't know; if `float_to_int()` is simply equivalent to `int(arg)` and if all the `xxx_to_int()` function are doing the same, I suppose that `to_int()` can be avoided and `buf` initialized as `int buf[sizeof...(Args)+1U] { cmd_id, int(args)... };`. But only the OP know what is doing `float_to_int()`

Comment: True, I didn't see that there wasn't a definition of `float_to_int`

Comment: float_to_int is effectively a reinterpret cast of the float (to an int).  As it turns out I think I can use max66's solution, and do a reinterpret cast of args, instead of to_int(args).  I really just need the 32 bits put in the buffer, without converting to an int value.  The other end knows to interpret the buffer as the correct type.

Comment: This seems to do what I want...  compiles, but haven't tested yet....int buf[sizeof...(Args)+1U]{ static_cast<int>(cmd_id), *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&args)... };  static_cast on cmd_id because it is an enumeration.

Comment: @ttemple That is technically undefined behavior and the compiler might optimize it weirdly; you should look into [the `may_alias` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#index-may_005falias-type-attribute) or equivalent for your compiler. Character pointers don’t have this problem, so if you’re just converting to that eventually you should see if you can skip the `int` step.

Comment: @Daniel H, I was doing the conversion with a union of int and float, which is probably more conventional.  I am really just trying to get those 4 bytes (the float) into an int buffer, without doing the implicit conversion to int.  Do you have any suggestions for how that can be done in the most efficient way?

Comment: @ttemple Unfortunately, there is no portable way to do that without using a character pointer and copying each byte, but you need to do endian conversion also if you care about portability, so that might not be much added cost. If you don’t care about it working on all the various compilers, what compiler are you using? If it’s GCC or Clang, `may_alias` with `reinterpret_cast` will work; otherwise, I’m not the right person to ask.

Comment: VS2015 currently.  Portability isn't a big issue right now, because there is a lot of MS specific code in the project that won't go away soon.